# Android, Serial Version ID does not match again and again

Tags: android, serialization

I have a mobile app with wearable.  The settings are stored at a serialized Java object.  That works fine on the phone.  But when I send them to the watch, I get SUID mismatch, over and over again.

I tied ADB uninstall the app on the watch and still same error:

```
adb -s 0390918d02a26f16  uninstall org.wordzoo.uhr.germanclock



java.io.InvalidClassException: org.wordzoo.uhr.germanclock.file.WordArrays; Incompatible class (SUID): org.wordzoo.uhr.germanclock.file.WordArrays: static final long serialVersionUID =4458778969075636174L; but expected org.wordzoo.uhr.germanclock.file.WordArrays: static final long serialVersionUID =2670788032868766877L;
06-13 13:44:01.906 17469-17469/org.wordzoo.uhr.germanclock W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.verifyAndInit(ObjectInputStream.java:2336)
06-13 13:44:01.906 17469-17469/org.wordzoo.uhr.germanclock W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1643)
```

Interesting that the error is in the WordArrays class which is a member of the settings class in question....  If it helps anyone else, last time I had this error I needed to go into build configurations, misc tab, and uncheck the don't deploy APK if no changes are detected )) arg...   but that is not helping this time...

Comment: do you set the IDs yourself?

Comment: So set the `serialVersionUID` to what is stated as expected in the error message; recompile; redeploy.

Comment: thanks, understood.  i would rather rely on the java spec/ART to choose when the classes are compatible and not compatible.

Comment: @tom That is overkill 99% of the time. Most of the time your classes are serialization-compatible even under a surprising amount of change. See the Object Versioning Chapter of the Object Serialization Specification.

Answer (score 0):

argh, it was the "miscellaneous" build configuration, "skip installation if apk has not changed".  i know i unchecked it (one week ago) and did not check it again myself and no one else is using this AS install...